How can i obtain a positive Vref for this circuit?
I have to design a irrigation system that uses a resistive moisture sensor to maintain a certain level of relative soil humidity for a plant. In order to convert the resistance changes of the moisture sensor (which varies from 10kohms to 850kohms) I used a active bridge. At the output I get voltage varying from 7.37V (for sensor resistance of 10kohms) and 0.013V (for sensor resistance of 850kohms). Then I have to convert this voltage variation of the sensor into a variation in the range of 2V-13V. I used a differential amplifier in order to get this, and I made it work perfectly, but I am not allowed to use negative voltage sources, and the Vref I obtained is negative. Also I am not allowed to use double power supply op-amps, what can I change in this circuit to obtain the same results, but with using only the positive power supply Vcc = 15V ?

Why are the inputs to U7 shorted? Presumably it's supposed to be a buffer. Please tag homework questions appropriately.

I accidentally shorted it, the negative input should go to OUT, and Vref to +

Utilize a virtual-ground.  True ground (according to your power supply) will become your "-Vcc" and supply max will be your "Vcc".  Use the mid-point for your circuit's "ground".

Solved!
Instead of using a differential amplifier I used a inverting voltage domain conversion amplifier.


What exactly is a "voltage domain conversion amplifier"? I've never heard that term before.
